# Reportes con angularjs

Tags: web, angular

Deseo crear reportes con angularjs, es un tema que recién estoy aprendiendo y no encuentro mucha ayuda en internet. Necesito saber como capturar datos de una base de datos y mostrarlos en gráficos con angular.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que comentas con tu duda, es bastante amplio lo que preguntas, es decir, desde cómo capturar los datos de una base de datos y cómo dibujarlos en el frontend. Eso implica varias cosas:

- Desarrollar un backend (PHP, Spring, Node...)
- Conexión con base de datos
- Exponer un servicio REST para que lo pueda consumir el cliente
- Diseñar la lógica de tu aplicativo

¿Tienes todo eso ya desarrollado? En ese caso, ¿para qué versión de Angular: 1.x o 2+?

Para mostrar gráficos tienes muchas opciones, desde gratuitas hasta de pago. ¿Podrías definir también cómo son los reportes que quieres crear, si sólo es dibujar gráficas o algo más?

Comment: Si solo es mostrar gráficos, como por ejemplo gráfico de barras, gráfico circular. Y estoy trabajando con angular 2, necesito un libro donde específicamente hable de eso, o talvez un tutorial, que sea con html, que trabaje tambien con servlets,o mejor dicho que sea en MVC